# Elastic APM instrumentation vs OpenTelemetry instrumentation

Tags: .net, open-telemetry, elastic-apm

I'm trying OpenTelemetry client with Elastic APM to log into Elastic APM server. There are several instrumentations that exists both in OTEL client and Elastic APM client, for example `AspNetCoreInstrumentation`. Do these do the same thing? Do I need to use both or either of them?

Sample usage:

```cs
services.AddOpenTelemetry()
                .ConfigureResource(resource => resource
                    .AddService(serviceName))
                .WithTracing(tracing => tracing
                    .AddSource(serviceName)
                    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()); // <-

...
hostbuilder.UseElasticApm(new AspNetCoreDiagnosticSubscriber()); // <-
```